# How to send in command line arguments for a python file execution in command line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python program that runs perfectly in Sublime text. The main function in the file has an argument (integer argument).

```
def main(number = input())
```

But when I tried to run it in command line such as,

```
$python testFile.py 56
```

It is giving me nothing. How is it possible to send an integer in the command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def main():
    number = int(sys.argv[1])  # this line will fail if you pass an argument that's not an integer
    print(number)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Don't forget to `import sys`. And maybe do a check on `len(sys.argv)`.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is `sys.argv`.

```
def main(number):
  print int(number)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main(sys.argv[1])
```

Then you will be able to pass what you want in `$python testFile.py 56`

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're invoking your `testFile.py` and providing an argument before your script has started (and read from `def main()`).

There are a handful of approaches you can use, but the easiest may be just using `sys.argv` to get command line arguments, e.g.

```
def main():
    number = int(sys.argv[1])

#this line calls main if you're calling the script directly:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note that it's poor form to give a mutable argument (e.g. 'input()') as a default in a method's signature.

Comment: `sys.argv` is a list - might want to check your notation :)

Answer (score 0):

As others have already suggested `sys.argv` can be used to get the command line arguments in your code.

But if for some odd reason you dont want to use that , you can also try passing the input using `pipe` in shell.

For example ,

```
$ echo '56' | python testFile.py
```